# MVC Controller.File returns blank pdf

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pdf, file-io, pdf-generation, download

I lost a lot of time on this issue so i will go straight to topic.
I am receiving empty pdf with correct number of (blank)pages. My action is:

```
     public FileResult DownloadDoc()
     { 
           //Authorization
           //initialising filename
           //getting content
           return File(Convert.FromBase64String(content), "application/pdf", filename); 
     }
```

Content is Base64 string and it is correct. I know because when i use system.io.file.writeallbytes to make document i'm getting correct one.
I also tried to return file over Response and result is the same.
There are no (I hope) razor syntax errors.

This part of code used to work, and he stopped despite no one made no change. Maybe IIS was restarted.

If anyone can tell me what else to try ... tnx

p.s. I am looking for way without saving doc on server side.

Comment: Did you upgrade Acrobat recently?

Comment: Perform a binary inspection client-side of what you received from the server. You should have something like `%PDF-1.6` at the top and `%%EOF` at the bottom, possibly with just a little whitespace afterwards.

Comment: I have %PDF-1.3 on start and %%EOF on the end.
It doesn't meter what reader i use.

Comment: Are you able to post the PDF somewhere so that we can examine it? The fact that you are getting "pages" and you have the header and trailer makes it appear that you're doing everything right.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry,
an error was in javascript that saves file after returning from the server.
If you have similar issues check **inner** properties of the Blob object!